# CSS vertical align based on height of other element

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to create a block with an image that contains content by your side, where I intend to align the image vertically based on the content's height. I've tried alignments with table/table-cell technique but I can't get what I want..

click here to see what I want:

[image]

Comment: Put your code in your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solve my question without using flex-box, I need it works in old browsers

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  background:#eee;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 450px;
}
img {
   position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with flex-box, here is one way to do it:

```css
body
{
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.gallery-item
{
  background-color: gray; 
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.gallery-item
{
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.gallery-item .image-container
{
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  align-self: center;
}

.gallery-item .image-container img
{ 
  margin: -20px auto;  
}

.gallery-item .text-container
{ 
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-item">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200">
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="gallery-item">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200">
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is a codePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGdGPV

A lot of the code is not mandatory, like the margins for `.gallery-item` and the `padding` for the body, but you get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

the first thing you have to do is put display: table to de container and display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle to lements inside the container.

Comment: This alone won't achieve the desired result. Some overflow of cells would need to occur.

Comment: Yep. We're all waiting. In the meantime, this is better as a comment.